# Pandasでif文に2つ以上の条件が入る変換

Tags: python, pandas

```
x1,..,y14
abc, ..., -
```

のようなデータフレームdfがあります。

x1 == 'abc' かつ y14 == '-' ならば y14 = '★'のような変換をしたいと考えております。

```
def henkan(x):
    if x == abc:
        return '★'

df.y14 = df.y14.apply(henkan)
```

のようなコードは思いつくのですが、条件が2つになる場合はどのように記述すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: `df.loc[(df.x1=='abc') & (df.y14=='-'), 'y14'] = '★'` とする方法もあります。

Comment: df.apply()を使用してのご要望の動作(列を跨いだ操作)は無理かと思います。

Comment: ちなみに質問のコードではエラーが発生して実行出来ませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問されていることを実行する場合、[Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) を利用して、

```py
df.loc[(df['x1'] == 'abc') & (df['y14'] == '-'), 'y14'] = '★'
```

等のようにするのが一般的です。

どうしても`.apply()`メソッドを用いる必要がある場合は以下のようになります。

```py
def henkan(x):
    if x['x1'] == 'abc' and x['y14'] == '-':
        x['y14'] = '★'
    return x

df = df.apply(henkan, axis=1)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。y14、の部分をy1~y14についてループさせる、ということは可能でしょうか？

Comment: for文を使ってコード中の`'y14'`の部分を変化させれば可能です。

Answer (score 0):

`and` を使えば良さそうです。

```
if x1 == 'abc' and y14 == '-' :
```

Comment: ｢if x == abc:｣のところを｢if x1 == 'abc' and y14 == '-' :｣に変更したら、実行出来ましたか？他にもコードを変更しましたか？私の方で試したところエラーが発生してしまいましたので教えてください。